# What these parts of speech symbols mean in this word list

Tags: parts-of-speech, lists

[This](https://www.wordfrequency.info/free.asp?s=y) word list has these strange symbols for parts of speech which I can't find documentation on. Wondering if one could list out what they mean.

- a: the (?)
- v: be (verb)
- c: and (conjunction)
- i: of (?)
- t: to (?)
- p: it (?)
- d: this (?)
- x: not (?)
- r: up (?)
- m: one (?)
- n: people (noun)
- j: other (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is on-topic here, but the [project FAQ](https://www.wordfrequency.info/100k_faq.asp) explains that the word list is based on [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), and like its parent uses the [CLAWS7](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/claws7tags.html) tagset for parts of speech. The basic usage is given by the first character, but even without knowing about CLAWS, you could probably have worked it out because the parts of speech identified in the list are all listed out in the third column.

- a: article
- c: conjunction
- d: determiner (though the listing says *demonstrative*)
- e: existential *there*
- i: preposition
- j: adjective
- m: number
- n: noun
- p: pronoun
- r: adverb
- t: infinitive marker *to*
- u: interjection
- v: verb
- x: negation with *not* or *n't*